# lenovo p52 thunderbolt docking station

Tags: 18.04

Currently, the only thing which works on this thunderbolt lenovo p52 docking station /ubuntu-18.04 is HDMI. All USBs and ethernet are "dead". Some comments claims, that these docking stations works in linux only after reboot(unplugging=reboot, plugging in=reboot), but I cannot confirm even that. For me it's just a dysfunctional brick.

Is there anything I can do to make it work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS issue with Dell Thunderbolt 3 Dock after update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1113764/ubuntu-18-04-1-lts-issue-with-dell-thunderbolt-3-dock-after-update) **If** the duplicate doesn't solve the issue let me know and I'll retract the close vote. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get it working: I had to do following changes in bios:

enable thunderbolt assistant
enable preboot
disable all thunderbold related security

after that my docking station of P52 works. But I'm using only USB ports (did not work before, works now), ethernet (same), and HDMI (worked even before). So it might have been related to that security, as I did not allow any of these devices, and out hdmi probably do not need authorization. Nevermind, it's working now.

but if someone have some hints how thunderbold device authorization (~security) works in linux, I'd be thankful for that.

Comment: For me everything except HDMIs/DisplayPorts is working with ubuntu 19.04/kernel 5.0.0.20 on P52 and Lenovo Thunderbolt 3 workstation dock. That's strange...

Comment: finally, after yesterday's update of nvidia-430 drivers HDMI started to work as expected so everything works for me now

Answer (score 0):

What is the version of your kernel ? Is it the latest version - 4.15.0.44 ? If so, maybe it's the same error that i had. I had to downgrade the kernel on 4.15.0.43 because the 4.15.0.44 broke the thunderbolt support...

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I managed to fix it right now. It's working for me even after kernel update to: 4.15.0-44-generic