# Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS issue with Dell Thunderbolt 3 Dock after update

Tags: 18.04, updates, dock, thunderbolt

I have been using Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS on a Dell Precision 5510 laptop with a Dell Thunderbolt 3 Dock, model TB16, for over two months with no issues. The system is regularly updated with the latest updates.

January 29th 2019, a notification for a new update appeared :

- Several unused kernel files to be deleted
- (update for Oracle's Virtual Box, seems very irrelevant)

I proceeded to install. However after rebooting, reaching the login screen and entering my password, I only had black screens and a completely unresponsive system.

After several reboots and attempts to diagnose the problem, only when I rebooted the system with the Dell Thunderbolt 3 Dock unplugged that the system successfully booted and displayed the desktop, menu bar...etc. Even then, when I re-plugged the dock, the system became unresponsive with a black screen.

I am currently looking into restoring the pre-update kernel using GRUB.

I'm interested to know if anyone, with a relatively similar setup, is experiencing this issue. Any other insights or ideas that could help are welcome.

Update :

Another report on this issue found (2 posts by the same author), it seems to affect only Dell docks but it is probably not restricted to Dell machines:

https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/678174

[After most recent kernel update (4.15.0-44-generic) my tablet freezes whenever plugged into docking station](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1113743/after-most-recent-kernel-update-4-15-0-44-generic-my-tablet-freezes-whenever-p/1113754#1113754)

For now the issue has been resolved by restoring 4.15.0-43-generic using GRUB. I am holding from updating Ubuntu until the bug gets fixed.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1113743/after-most-recent-kernel-update-4-15-0-44-generic-my-tablet-freezes-whenever-p/1113754#1113754

Comment: I have the same problem with a Lenovo T460s and a LENOVO® ThinkPad® Ultra Dock 90W. So the problem is neither Dell specific nor depends on the Thunderbolt dock, but seems to be a more general one. I had to downgrade to Kernel 14.15.0.43 as Kernel 14.15.0.44 seems to be buggy.

Comment: Same problem for me (ThinkPad X1 Carbon 5th + Dock Thunderbolt 3)
Seems to work again after a downgrade to kernel 4.15.0-43

Comment: There are similar issues on my desktop + 2 monitors setup (both display port). Seems it is not necessary related to a dock, but more to external graphics. Downgrading the kernel works as a workaround.

Comment: Same problem here with XPS13 + dock and 2 monitors

Comment: Same problem here with XPS 13 9360. I can use the dock only if I deactivate Thunderbolt direct access in Ubuntu settings. And then I can have charge + screen but nothing else.

Answer (score 10):

I am posting to confirm I had this same issue after a kernel update yesterday.

Same symptoms, wouldn't boot with the dock plugged in. Plugging the dock in after laptop boots standalone caused the laptop screen to go black and everything lock up.

Tried with everything disconnected from the dock except power (as I thought the laptop was having issues going to the dual monitors).

Had to roll back from linux-image-4.15.0-44-generic (4.15.0-44.47) to linux-image-4.15.0-43-generic (4.15.0-43.46) and the Dell dock + monitor is working for me now.

## Solution

Press <kbd>ESC</kbd> on boot (UEFI) or Left <kbd>Shift</kbd> if BIOS, then select advanced boot options. I went to older kernel (-43). Confirmed issue wasn't occurring for me on -43, so removed -44.

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-4.15.0-44-generic
```

Comment: I had to add `-f` to the purge command due to "not empty" errors.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Upgrading kernel to 4.15.0-45 (available today on Ubuntu repositories) solved if for me! At last!

Comment: I can confirm that updating the kernel solved the problem. First, do `uname -a` to verify that you have 4.15.0-44. Then, do `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to update. After rebooting, I was able to use my dock as before.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt remove linux-image-4.15.0-44-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-44-generic
```

This helped me.
Ubuntu 18.04.
Dell XPS 9570 + thunderbolt tb16

Comment: You probably don't want to remove the currently active kernel, though. Reboot into -43 first.